# Establish connection with downloaded database file [WP8]

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, sqlconnection

I use a local pre-populated database file (added in the project folder) in order to access the needed data. In order to make it work with SQLiteAsyncConnection, one should change the attribute "Build Action" (to "Content") in the properties of the file.

That change is easy when it's a local file added in the IDE. 
What about a downloaded database file?

I downloaded a new version of my database and stored it in the IsolatedStorage. When I try to query this db, I get an "SQLiteException" error -the same that I was getting in case I had forgotten to change the above mentioned property.

Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Can you provide details for the SQLiteException? Additionally, I usually check the ReadOnly flag on the file just to eliminate it as a potential problem.

Comment: Eventually, I made it work using:
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite"), true);

instead of SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("db.sqlite");